# SQL - trying to add an IDENTITY but the joining table already has an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, addition, identity

I'm trying to update a mail table with random bank names from a fake bank name table. Issue is the mail table already contains an identity field so I'm getting the error

> Multiple identity columns specified for table 'generic_banks'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.

Here's my code:

```
ALTER TABLE generic_banks ADD ID_new INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON generic_banks(ID_new)

UPDATE m
SET m.alias = b.bank_alias
FROM mail_detail_lz m
INNER LOOP JOIN generic_banks b ON b.ID_new = (1 +  ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)%50000))
```

Please help

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  A table can have only one identity column.  What are you finding unclear?

Comment: I was hoping there was another way to create another ID... Or maybe not use identity.

Comment: I executed the first line twice which is why i got the error. The code does actually work..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a random name from one table to another, I might suggest something more like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select m.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from mail_detail_lz m
     ),
     gb as (
      select gb.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from generic_banks gb
    )
update toupdate
    set alias = gb.bank_alias
    from toupdate join
         gb
         on toupdate.seqnum = gb.seqnum;
```

This is a generic approach that doesn't allow duplicates.  If it doesn't work for you then something similar should work.

Comment: OK, this updates only 10 records. There are almost 3 million records in the mail table (mail_detail_lz)

Answer (score 0):

Only one identity column can be created per table. [MS Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

You will either need to create ID_new field as a non-identity field or remove the existing identify field.